# How can I fix the broken use statement in chapter 2 of ``Entirely Too Many Lists''?

Tags: rust

If I try to test the final code (including hidden code which wraps the whole file in a main function) of [chapter 2 of Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-final.html) I get this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `super::List`    --> src/second.rs:110:9
    | 110 |     use super::List;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `List` in `second`
```

Turns out if I remove the hidden code that wraps a main function around the displayed code I can run tests just fine. This does raise the question of what the purpose was of this hidden code that broke the use statement. Also no variation on that use statement (::List, crate::List, List, no use statement) fixes the error if I leave the main function there.

**Question:** Can the use statement be fixed while the main remains there? If not why is the main function there at all?

Comment: You'll have to give more context. I pasted the _exact_ code from your link and it works, without modification: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f66ebf7ba020c504f6b19943fa588386

Comment: The hidden code is added automagically by `mdbook` when converting markdown to HTML. In this case it shouldn't have been added and you should ignore it.

Comment: @PeterHall, you forgot the hidden code that apparently is courtesy of mdbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the `use` statement be fixed while the main remains there?

No, [`super`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.super.html) will refer to the encompassing *module*, not the function scope. There is no path that can name it as far as I'm aware. You *could* wrap everything within `main` in another module, so `super` can find it that way:

```
fn main() {
    mod inner {
        struct List;
        mod tests {
            use super::List;
        }
    }
}
```

---

> If not why is the main function there at all?

mdBook just [mimics](https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook/issues/712) the behavior of rustdoc which does [wrap code samples with `fn main()` if not provided](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#pre-processing-examples). This is not typically a problem since rustdoc examples wouldn't normally have the typical `mod tests` structure. Its unfortunate that this isn't handled though.